# gulp-file-include and BrowserSync Doesn't Reflect the Changes to Browser

Tags: gulp, gulp-browser-sync

I am trying to use [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include) for include some common sections like header or footer from `/src/includes` folder into any .html pages in a project tree along with [BrowserSync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) to refresh changes.

When I use `gulp` command from command line it's compiling all files into `/dist` folder without problems (I hope). But after, if I change anything from `/src/index.html` it doesn't reflect changes to browser or write changes into `/dist/index.html`.

I can't figure out exactly where the problem is. You can see the project from [this Git repo](https://github.com/fatihturan/HTMLBase) and here is my `gulpfile.js` content:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sourcemaps  = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include");

// File Paths
var CSS_PATH = { src: "./src/sass/*.scss", dist: "./dist/css/"};
var JS_PATH = { src: "./src/js/*.js", dist: "./dist/js/"};
var HTML_PATH = { src: "./src/*.html", dist: "./dist/html/*.html"};
var INCLUDES_PATH = "./src/includes/**/*.html";
var JQUERY_PATH = "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";

// Error Handling
var gulp_src = gulp.src;
gulp.src = function() {
  return gulp_src.apply(gulp, arguments)
    .pipe(plumber(function(error) {
      // Output an error message
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Error (' + error.plugin + '): ' + error.message));
      // emit the end event, to properly end the task
      this.emit('end');
    })
  );
};

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(CSS_PATH["src"])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_PATH["dist"]))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(concat("main.css", {newLine: ""}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_PATH["dist"]))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src([JS_PATH["src"], JQUERY_PATH])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(JS_PATH["dist"]));
});

// File Include
gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  return gulp.src(HTML_PATH["src"])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: 'src/includes'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// BrowserSync
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'dist/'
    },
    open: false,
    browser: "Google Chrome",
    notify: true,
    notify: {
        styles: {
            top: 'auto',
            bottom: '0',
            borderRadius: '4px 0 0 0',
            opacity: .9
        }
    },
    snippetOptions: {
      rule: {
        match: /<\/body>/i,
        fn: function (snippet, match) {
          return snippet + match;
        }
      }
    }
  })
})

// Watch task
gulp.task('watch', ['fileinclude', 'browserSync'], function() {
  gulp.watch(CSS_PATH["src"], ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(JS_PATH["src"], ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(INCLUDES_PATH, ['fileinclude']);
  gulp.watch([HTML_PATH["src"], HTML_PATH["src"]], browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['fileinclude', 'styles', 'scripts', 'browserSync', 'watch' ]);
```

Comment: You have the tasks 'fileinclude' and 'browserSync' in both the 'default' and 'watch' tasks.  Take the reference to them out of the 'watch' task and see if that helps.  You don't want to be running the browserSync task over and over so I am not surprised that it is not working properly.

Comment: Also your gulp.watch on the html files is duplicated, remove one.  You could just use the syntax HTML_PATH.src and similar throughout, instead of HTML_PATH["src"].

Comment: @Mark I've edited the `gulpfile.js` as you say (you can find the edited file from [here](https://jsbin.com/disahobayo/edit?js)). But this time it doesn't refresh or `gulp-file-include` doesn't work properly. Did I edited the `gulpfile.js` wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have it working.  I added the following to the end of the `'scripts'` and `'fileinclude'` tasks:

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))


//  File Include
gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  return gulp.src(HTML_PATH.src)
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: 'src/includes'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // return gulp.src([JS_PATH["src"], JQUERY_PATH])
  return gulp.src(JS_PATH.src)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(JS_PATH.dist))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
});
```

so that the browser is reloaded after any changes to those two groups.  I changed the `'watch'` task to:

```
// Watch task

// gulp.task('watch', ['fileinclude', 'browserSync'], function() {
//  'browserSync' is already running from 'default' task so remove it from above
//  'fileinclude' is called below only where it is needed, not for changes to js/scss files

gulp.task('watch',  function() {
  gulp.watch(CSS_PATH.src, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(JS_PATH.src, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(INCLUDES_PATH, ['fileinclude']);

  // gulp.watch([HTML_PATH["src"], HTML_PATH["src"]], browserSync.reload);
  // the above looks for changes to the source and immediately reloads,
  //    before any changes are made to the dist/html

  // Watch for changes in the html src and run 'fileinclude'
  //  browserSync reload moved to end of 'fileinclude'

  gulp.watch([HTML_PATH.src], ['fileinclude']);
});
```

**Edit**: to handle the subsequent question about gulp failing to watch new files, I have made some changes to my original answer.  But you should really be using gulp4.0 now IMO.  Gulp3.9.x relied on a library that was problematic in watching for new, deleted or renamed files.

You will need two more plugins:

```
var watch = require("gulp-watch");
var runSequence = require("run-sequence");
```

The `gulp-watch` plugin is better at watching for new, etc. files, but doesn't take 'tasks' as arguments but instead it takes functions as arguments so that is why I used run-sequence.  [You could rewrite your tasks as regular functions - but then you might as well shift to gulp4.0].

Then use this `'watch'` task:

gulp.task('watch', function () {

```
  watch(CSS_PATH.src, function () {
    runSequence('styles');
  });
  watch(JS_PATH.src, function () {
    runSequence('scripts');
  });
  watch(INCLUDES_PATH,  function () {
    runSequence('fileinclude');
  });
  watch([HTML_PATH.src], function () {
    runSequence('fileinclude');
  });
});
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for your reply. But if I create a new `.html` file into `/src/` folder it doesn't compile into `/dist/` until restart `gulp`. Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Yes, the short answer is to upgrade to gulp4.0.  See  https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/651 But with some changes you can do it gulp3.9.x  I edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. New files are compiling into `/dist` folder. But this time if I open the new file in browser (i.e.: `http://localhost:3000/test.html`) and change something in this file BrowserSync doesn't reload the page.

Comment: That is a separate question - about browser-sync - you should ask in a new question if you wish.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful and accurate.

Comment: Oh, sorry for forgetting to accept the answer. Thank you a lot. I am appreciated for your help. I will create another question about last issue.

Comment: By the way I tried to ask it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829282/browsersync-doesnt-trigger-refresh-except-index-html